# Email Alerts/Logs when Azure Container Instance Succeeds/Fails

Tags: azure, azure-container-instances

Is there any way to setup email alerts for when individual Azure Container Instances succeed or fail (or basically change state)? I have some run-once containers I kick off periodically, and would like to be notified when they complete and the status of the completion. Bonus if the email can include logs from the container, as well. Is this possible using the built-in alerts?

So far I haven't been able to make it work with the provided signals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont believe there is an automatic way so what I did was created a small timer based function that runs every 5 minutes and gets a list of all containers and checks the status. If any are in say a failed state it then uses SendGrid to sent an alert email.

UPDATE for Dan

I use Managed Service Identity in my function so I have a container tasks class like the below, can't remember exactly where I got the help to generate the GetAzure function as obviously when doing local debug you can't use the MSI credentials and the local account on Visual Studio that is meant to work doesn't appear to. However I think it might have been here - https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/4968

```
public static class ContainerTasks
{
    private static readonly IAzure azure = GetAzure();

    private static IAzure GetAzure()
    {
        var tenantId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DevLocalDbgTenantId");
        var clientId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DevLocalDbgClientId");
        var clientSecret = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DevLocalDbgClientSecret");
        AzureCredentials credentials;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tenantId) &&
            !string.IsNullOrEmpty(clientId) &&
            !string.IsNullOrEmpty(clientSecret))
        {
            var sp = new ServicePrincipalLoginInformation
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                ClientSecret = clientSecret
            };
            credentials = new AzureCredentials(sp, tenantId, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
        }
        else
        {
            credentials = SdkContext
                .AzureCredentialsFactory
                .FromMSI(new MSILoginInformation(MSIResourceType.AppService), AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
        }
        var authenticatedAzure = Azure
            .Configure()
            .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic)
            .Authenticate(credentials);
        var subscriptionId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DevLocalDbgSubscriptionId");
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(subscriptionId))
            return authenticatedAzure.WithSubscription(subscriptionId);
        return authenticatedAzure.WithDefaultSubscription();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<IContainerGroup> ListTaskContainers(string resourceGroupName, ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"Getting a list of all container groups in Resource Group '{resourceGroupName}'");

        return azure.ContainerGroups.ListByResourceGroup(resourceGroupName);
    }
}
```

Then my monitor function is simply

```
public static class MonitorACIs
{
    [FunctionName("MonitorACIs")]
    public static void Run([TimerTrigger("%TimerSchedule%")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"MonitorACIs Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
        foreach(var containerGroup in ContainerTasks.ListTaskContainers(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ResourceGroupName"), log))
        {
            if(String.Equals(containerGroup.State, "Failed"))
            {
                log.LogInformation($"Container Group {containerGroup.Name} has failed please investigate");
                Notifications.FailedTaskACI(containerGroup.Name, log);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notifications.FailedTaskACI is just a class method that sends an email to one of our Teams channels

It's not perfect but it does the job for now!

Comment: Interesting! Have you thought at all about using a sidecar container to do something similar, since you can run multiple containers in the same group with ACI?

Comment: I kinda do that already but with another function, I have a function that creates a container group with a single container to do the task (short lived tasks that take about 30s - 5m tops), when that task completes it fires a message to a queue and another function monitors for completed tasks and nukes the relevant container. A 3rd party gfx lib I'm using though has a habit of crashing on Linux with no warning so I have a 3rd 3 line monitor function which just alerts me of any failed containers and I can go take a look at the logs on the off chance an exception made it out!

Comment: Nice. Mind sharing what your 3rd monitor function looks like? :)

Comment: Thanks, appreciate seeing what you did! This is helpful.